# Getting DIV content with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

How can I get content of a DIV using regular expression. What I need to get is in between;

```
<div class="lv1right dfbg">......</div>
```

Also there are several (not well defined) tags between these div tags, and I would like to get all of them..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd avoid using regexps for HTML, since HTML isn't regular. Instead check out [this PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), which will allow you to extract/change the HTML much more reliably.

Comment: Second, HTML is too irregular for regular expressions

Comment: +1 first Don't Process HTML With Regex post of the day. Many more to come, I'm sure.

Comment: HTML is not always perfect but browsers render it anyway. This would make regex not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<div.*>).*?(?=</div>)
```

Comment: Will this work for nested div tags? <div class="lv1right dfbg"><div></div></div>

Comment: To get the nested ones could you not apply a recursive method that applies this regex (edited to: (?<=<div.*>).*(?=</div>)) to the match string(being the match value from the previous match).

Comment: No making it greedy will not cause it to match nested divs. It merely causes to match everything between the first `div` and the last `</div>` to be matched (iff DOT-ALL is enabled: the DOT does not match line breaks by default).