# Getting div data without using DOM

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting DIV content with Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700459/getting-div-content-with-regular-expression)

Let me first tell you that DOM is not an option on this one.
I simply have the html :

```
className">Name</div>......</div>....</div>
```

Now, i have created a regular expression like :

```
$match_count = preg_match_all('/className\">(.*)\<\/div\>/', $page, $matches);
```

This would seem fine to me, but for some reason, it gets more data than expected. That is, it finishes some closing divs later. How can i restrict it so that it gets the data only inside the first closing div ?

Comment: It looks like you have nested `div`s. By "first div" do you mean `<div>` that appears first in the document (along with all inner `div`s) or do you want the first inner most `div`? If it is the later, I am afraid that you can't do that with just regular expressions.

Comment: Why is DOM not an option? Not installed/not available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$match_count = preg_match_all('/className">(.*?)<\/div>/', $page, $matches);
```

use non greedy selector `.*?`

Comment: also no need to escape < > and "

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` instead. It will stop searching after the first matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$match_count = preg_match_all('/className\">(.*)\<\/div\>/', $page, $matches);
```

The U pattern modifier will make sure it finds the smallest possible match, not the biggest.